# In Unity, How can I serialize an object at Edit time, and also bind the object fields to UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am writing a design-time level editor.

I would like my levels to be defined in JSON, and loaded/saved using Json serialization (Probably NewtonSoft)

The issue I have is this:

- In order to have the objects be serializable, they cannot be Unity Objects (e.g. ScriptableObject) (and, indeed, I don’t need them to be – except
- In order to bind custom editor stuff to the object’s properties, the objects need to be unity Objects.

I can’t figure out what to do – and figured people must be doing something similar, but my Google skills are failing me (and I have googled A LOT!

As a really simple example:

1. I have a class called `Level`, with a `string` field called `LevelName`
2. I have an `EditorWindow` which has a reference the current Level instance
3. If `Level` is a `MonoBehaviour`, I can say
   `_so = new SerializedObject(_level);` and I can bind a field in my UI to the `LevelName` field
4. That works fine – but now I want to save the data – but when I try to serialise it I get an error:

> NotSupportedException: rigidbody property has been deprecated

This, my searching tells me, is simply because you can’t serialize unity Object.

But if I change Level to be a POCO (i.e. not inheriting from anything) then the binding doesn’t work because _level is not a UnityEngine.Object

I feel I may be missing something really obvious, but for the moment I am stuck and would really appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: _[Odin - Inspector and Serializer (custom serialisation, effortless editors and more)](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/odin-inspector-and-serializer-89041#description)_

Comment: ...apart from that you could create a serialisable POCO moniker (a term popular in COM development) class that represents the object in question.  You can display it in the editor and be able to save the settings.  More importantly it is able to re-create the Unity `MonoBehaviour` and attach it to the appropriate `GameObject` (basically what Unity would normally do) but you are free to use whatever serialisation method you want.

Comment: Thanks @MickyD - I'd be really interested if you can point me at anything about 'moniker' - the only thing I could find was a class in the Visual Studio SDK! 
Been programming for 45 years and never heard the term!
The problem with your suggestion, though, is that in order to be used in the Editor it would have to be a UnityObject - and therefore couldn't be serialized.. :(
Odin may be a an option, but I figure surely folks brighter than me have solved this issue without buying additional software - the fun is in the coding :)

Comment: _"45 years"_ - hehe, similar 40.  So monikers came up alot when I was doing COM programming. _"that in order to be used in the Editor it would have to be a UnityObject"_ -  yesss but that's not the POCO object `P` you will be serialising as JSON.   You can plonk `P` into a `ScriptableObject`, let's say `S` that your custom editor `E` can display a GUI for and remember it should refer to the members in `S.MyPocoChildObject`.  Save `P`.  During loading, you load `P` and call a moniker create method like `MyBehaviour MyPMoniker.CreateAndAttachTo(GameObject go, S s)`

Comment: @MickyD I see what you're getting at, yes thanks.
I kinda started writing something like that, but the other way around (wrap the Unity Object in a POCO and mark it as not serializeable) but it was complex enough that I stopped.
What makes the whole thing slightly more complex is that I actually have a collection of POCOs as a property of the main POCO - so they would need a moniker too I think..
Hmm thanks - you've given me food for thought!

Comment: Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9aeNtKKXeo) from the makers of Homeworld: Deserts of Kharak.  In it they discuss tons of great developer practices including how they did alot of their code external to Unity using plain-old C# classes.  Only the most  important bits were made as Unity types such as MonoBehaviours